# Filmed lectures by Jürgen Moser

Tags: ho.history-overview

Are there any filmed lectures by outstanding German mathematician Jürgen Moser (July 4, 1928 – December 17, 1999)?

Comment: I'd guess probably not, since the current technology hadn't progressed too far at the time he was most active (especially at Courant, but also in Zurich).   His highest profile lectures were at ICMs, the last in 1998, but I'm unaware of any filmed versions of those.

Comment: It's not that long ago! Camcorders came out in the 1980's.  Whether anybody actually
did make recordings of Jurgen's lectures is another matter.